# Differentiation of the norm

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $f = f(t,x) = f(t, x_1, \cdots , x_n) . $ If $f \in C^1 ([0,M],W^{s,2}(\Bbb R^n))$ (which means that $g(t) :=\| f \|_{W^{s,2}(\Bbb R^n)}$ is differentiable on $[0,M]$ and $\frac{d}{dt} g(t)$ is continuous on $[0,M]$), then can I conclude that $h(t) :=  \| \partial_t f \|_{W^{s,2}(\Bbb R^n)} $ is also continuous on $[0,M]$?
Here $W^{s,2}$ means the general Sobolev space, and let $s$ be an integer.